# How to append the file name to a character string in the file

Tags: perl, shell, unix

I have a couple of files in the following format:

```
chr10   Cufflinks   transcript  92828   95504   1   -   .   gene_id "CUFF.1"; transcript_id "ENST00000447903"; FPKM "0.0000000000"; frac "0.000000"; conf_lo "0.000000"; conf_hi "0.000000"; cov "0.000000"; full_read_support "no";
chr10   Cufflinks   exon    92828   94054   1   -   .   gene_id "CUFF.1"; transcript_id "ENST00000447903"; exon_number "1"; FPKM "0.0000000000"; frac "0.000000"; conf_lo "0.000000"; conf_hi "0.000000"; cov "0.000000";
chr10   Cufflinks   exon    94555   94665   1   -   .   gene_id "CUFF.1"; transcript_id "ENST00000447903"; exon_number "2"; FPKM "0.0000000000"; frac "0.000000"; conf_lo "0.000000"; conf_hi "0.000000"; cov "0.000000";
chr10   Cufflinks   exon    94744   94852   1   -   .   gene_id "CUFF.1"; transcript_id "ENST00000447903"; exon_number "3"; FPKM "0.0000000000"; frac "0.000000"; conf_lo "0.000000"; conf_hi "0.000000"; cov "0.000000";
chr10   Cufflinks   exon    95348   95504   1   -   .   gene_id "CUFF.1"; transcript_id "ENST00000447903"; exon_number "4"; FPKM "0.0000000000"; frac "0.000000"; conf_lo "0.000000"; conf_hi "0.000000"; cov "0.000000";
```

What I am trying to achieve is to get a file name appended to the character `CUFF*` in the input file. The name of my file is *sample_1*, so the output should look as follows:

```
chr10   Cufflinks   transcript  92828   95504   1   -   .   gene_id "CUFF.1_sample_1"; transcript_id "ENST00000447903"; FPKM "0.0000000000"; frac "0.000000"; conf_lo "0.000000"; conf_hi "0.000000"; cov "0.000000"; full_read_support "no";
chr10   Cufflinks   exon    92828   94054   1   -   .   gene_id "CUFF.1_sample_1"; transcript_id "ENST00000447903"; exon_number "1"; FPKM "0.0000000000"; frac "0.000000"; conf_lo "0.000000"; conf_hi "0.000000"; cov "0.000000";
chr10   Cufflinks   exon    94555   94665   1   -   .   gene_id "CUFF.1_sample_1"; transcript_id "ENST00000447903"; exon_number "2"; FPKM "0.0000000000"; frac "0.000000"; conf_lo "0.000000"; conf_hi "0.000000"; cov "0.000000";
chr10   Cufflinks   exon    94744   94852   1   -   .   gene_id "CUFF.1_sample_1"; transcript_id "ENST00000447903"; exon_number "3"; FPKM "0.0000000000"; frac "0.000000"; conf_lo "0.000000"; conf_hi "0.000000"; cov "0.000000";
chr10   Cufflinks   exon    95348   95504   1   -   .   gene_id "CUFF.1_sample_1"; transcript_id "ENST00000447903"; exon_number "4"; FPKM "0.0000000000"; frac "0.000000"; conf_lo "0.000000"; conf_hi "0.000000"; cov "0.000000";
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
cat sample_1 | sed 's/CUFF*/CUFF*_sample1/g'
```

Any Unix one-liner would be great...

Comment: I can't easily see the difference — it isn't visible in the unscrolled data and isn't obvious in the scrolled data (it's actually that `oId "CUFF.14.1";` needs to become `oId "CUFF.14.1_sample1";`).  Please redo the question, chopping out many more columns and explaining clearly what's the difference between the input and the output, and where the extra information comes from.  Was the sample data file called `sample1`?  What if it was called `sample1.txt` or otherwise had suffixes?  What about if it had a path `/path/to/sample1`?   **What have _you_ tried** (and what was the problem)?

Comment: Hello All, I have edited my question..Thanks for the comments....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sed` - and particularly regular expressions -  don't work like that. Have a read of [`perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) for how to write regular expressions.

In particular - `*` doesn't work the same as you might be used to - it's a pattern quantifier, not a wild card. It applies to the previous "symbol". So in your expression, you're replacing 'CUF' followed by zero or more instances of "F". So it will match "CUF", "CUFF" and "CUFFFFFFFF".

But not "CUFF.1".

And on the right hand side of the expression, it's not even doing that.

Maybe you want:

```
perl -pe 's/(CUFF[^"]+)/$1_sample/g' sample_1
```

Use `-i` if you want to inplace edit.

(Note - using perl because it definitely works. You can certainly do something quite similar with `sed` though).

Comment: Thank so much it worked..:)